# CARA risk-parameter estimation for discrete data as in Holt and Laury (2002)

Tags: microeconomics, uncertainty, risk-aversion

I have a dataset with around 40 participants who choose between a pair of lotteries A or B while the probabilities of prizes change. This setting is similar to that in Holt and Laury (2002): Risk Aversion and Incentive Effects, as shown below:
[image]

Each participant makes 9 choices. The tenth choice is omitted.

My question is: how to derive CARA risk-parameter estimates (upper and lower bound) from said data? What do I need to assume to come to such a conclusion? I suppose I need to assume some kind of a CARA utility function <strike>$$U(x)=\frac{1-\exp \left(-\alpha x^{1-r}\right)}{\alpha}$$</strike>  and form inequalities around the point where the expected payoff difference changes signs, but I get stuck there.